# C# System.NotImplementedException: NModbus4 error "function code 28 is not supported" with function WriteSingleCoil()

Tags: c#, windows

When I use NModbus4 in C#, the shared library is the program running into the function WriteSingleCoil().System.NotImplementedException:"function code 28 is not supported"

I wanted to use the NModbus4 shared library to control the solenoid switch through the IO module, but I was troubled by the occasional error when the program ran to the WriteSingleCoil () function: System.NotImplementedException:"function code 28 is not supported" .sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, it would be better to _show_ your code with a [mre]. Depending on what you're doing, this may be better written as a bug report.

Comment: You also probably want to add a `modbus` tag to your question. While you are editing tags, remove `windows`; this has nothing to do with windows

Comment: Never heard of [Modbus function code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) 28.